# How can I find a limit using equivalent functions and substitutions ( without applying L'Hospital) for the following problem:

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How can I find a limit using equivalent functions and substitutions ( without applying L'Hospital) for the following problem?

[There you can see the expression, I need to find the limit for, as x tends to 0](http://www.hostmath.com/Show.aspx?Code=e%5E%7B(cos%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D-1)%5Ctimes%201%2Fx%7D)

$\exp[(\cos(\sqrt x)-1)/x]$, square brackets for clarity.

Comment: Hint: try using the power reduction formula for sine.

Comment: Then it would be $$exp[(sinx)/x]$$ which is one? Could it be the solution of the problem be $$e^1$$?

Comment: Not quite.  Note that $\frac{ \cos(\sqrt{x}) - 1}{x} = \frac{-2 (\sin(\sqrt{x}))^2}{x} = -2 (\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x})^2$.

Comment: now I simplified: $$e^{-\frac{2\sin ^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{x^2}}$$ Then It I would take the root of x in front of the expression it would fraction with -2 so the solution would be $$e^{-1}$$?

Comment: Sorry, I should have typed $\frac{-2(\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x} = -2 ( \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}})^2$.  What can you say about $\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$ as $x$ tends to $0$ from the right?

Comment: It tends to one? So then it's $$e^{-2}$$?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems as though I cannot either upvote you nor accept your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You may set $x = t^2$ and use

- $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2} = \frac{1}{2}$ (easy to verify with L'Hospital).

\begin{eqnarray*} e^{\frac{\cos\sqrt x -1}{x}}
& = & e^{\frac{\cos t -1}{t^2}}\\
& \stackrel{t\to 0}{\longrightarrow} & e^{-\frac{1}{2}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\\
\end{eqnarray*}